# Hive - searching in an indexed or sorted column read a whole bucket

Tags: sorting, hive, bucket, orc

Queries in hive **don't use the Sort** and **read a whole bucket**. Is that normal or is that a misunderstanding.

Table :

```
col_a; col_b; values;
```

1. Specifications:

   - My Table is bucketed and sorted by "col_a" column.
   - Table have ORC format
2. Results:

   - When i query "col_a", **a whole bucket is read**.
   - When i index "col_b" and query "col_b", **more than a whole bucket is read**.
3. Table configs :

   - inputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat
   - outputFormat:    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat
   - serializationLib:    org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde
   - bucketCols: [col_a]
   - sortCols: col_a
   - order : 1
4. Insert to populate the table and select to get a value :

   ```
   hive.enforce.sorting=true;
   hive.enforce.bucketing=true;

   FROM table_temp 
   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_sorted PARTITION (date=1) SELECT
   col_a,
   col_b
   DISTRIBUTE BY col_a SORT BY col_a;

   SELECT * from table_sorted where date=1 AND col_a=986123;
   ```
5. What i thought

   I thought sort could allows us not to read the whole bucket but allow us to access a specific row or a range of rows. I also thought indexes could give us a row or a range in a bucket. Am i wrong ? Thank you for your time by the way!